# xinit error in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i am getting this below error and not sure what to do with this?
got this error when i was trying to execute xsetroot for display fucntion on screen

os : ubuntu

X.Org X Server 1.20.4

X Protocol Version 11,
Revision 0

Build Operating System: Linux 4.18.0-25-generic x86_64

Current Operating System: Linux buildroot 5.0.0-next-20190306 #8 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 3 13:03:08 BST 2019 aarch64

Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait

Current version of pixman: 0.38.4

Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.

Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Jan  1 00:00:25 1970

(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"

(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   20.873076] sun6i_dsi_get_video_start_delay: delay = 1942

[   20.873087] sun6i_dsi_get_drq_edge0: tcon0_div = 6

[   20.873091] edge0 = 586, edge1 = 893, line_num = 1147

[   20.873099] sun6i_dsi_setup_inst_loop: delay = 7

[   20.873116] hsa = 0, hbp = 0, hfp = 0, hblk = 3240, vblk = 0

modprobe: module g2d_23 not found in modules.dep

/usr/bin/Xorg: can't resolve symbol 'shadowUpdatePackedWeak'

xinit: giving up

xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused

xinit: server error

any help is much appreciated 
Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. When are you seeing this error? How are you starting X? What operating system are you using? You had tagged this with both Debian and Ubuntu, which is impossible. Please mention the operating system and its version in the body of your question (don't use tags for that).

Comment: when i check the log files i get fturbo issue

Comment: Please don't undo edits that correct your grammar and fix your formatting! You can use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format the output as code so that it is readable here. Also, tell us the _exact_ command you used, the version/distribution of Linux as I asked before and what logs files you check for what fturbo issue. We can't help you if you don't explain what is happening.